MediaWiki; PHP errors
I'm running MediaWiki (latest) in the oficial docker container, but have two errors showing.

Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/includes/Setup.php on line 368

I've looked at Setup.php on line 368 and found: $wgServerName = $serverParts['host'];
I'm wondering if this can't populate because I'm running it through a reverse proxy (NPM)?  PHPINFO() shows the FQDN I'm using though wiki.xx.yy

PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool
Now for this one it doesn't give me a file or a line to look at so I'm quite stuck here.
Wiki Screenshot

This is a fresh install of mediawiki docker (latest) but with a few tweaks to allow for uploads and uploads with bigger than the standard limit of 2MB.
I've enabled debugging to show the bottom error, but the top error shows even with no debugging on, also upon any submission (POST) of a form a blank wiki page is shown (as below)
Blank wiki page after submitting edit

I think you need to set either $wgServerName or $wgCanonicalServer in LocalSettings.php (mounted to the container, I think).

Turns out there was a line in LocalSettings.php that was overriding my setting of $wgServer.
This is that line, commenting it out makes it work fine, not sure how that line got in there but there you go: $wgServer="{$wgScriptPath}/images";
